# Messenger Bot Webview beginShareFlow not working

Tags: facebook, webview, bots, chatbot, messenger

I have a messenger bot [webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview) with a form with option to select, I am having an issue with message back to the thread using beginShareFlow. I have added Messenger Extensions JS SDK for the Webview. How do i implement this? Any link real world example is helpful.

Comment: Some code please!

Answer (score 0):

Compose a JSON message to send back to the thread, and then on user share button click or whatever event you wish, run MessengerExtensions.startShareFlow, passing in functions to handle success and error events, the message you created, and the message share type. Find more at [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/sharing/v2.9)

```
<script>
    var messageToShare = {
      "attachment":{
         "type":"template",
         "payload":{
             "template_type":"generic",
             "elements": [{
                 "title":"I took Peter's 'Which Hat Are You?' Quiz",
                 "image_url": "https://bot.peters-hats.com/img/hats/fez.jpg",
                 "subtitle": "My result: Fez",
                 "default_action":{
                     "type":"web_url",
                     "url": "https://bot.peters-hats.com/view_quiz_results.php?user=24601"
                 },
                 "buttons":[{
                     "type":"web_url",
                     "url":"https://bot.peters-hats.com/hatquiz.php?referer=24601",
                     "title":"Take the Quiz"
                 }]
             }]
         }
      }
    };

    MessengerExtensions.beginShareFlow(function success(response) {
    // Share successful

    }, function error(errorCode, errorMessage) {      
    // The user was not able to share

    },
    messageToShare,
    "broadcast");    
</script>
```